# How to concatenate two .aac files with the ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I get the command similar to:

> ffmpeg concat audio1.aac audio2.aac result.aac

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the concat protocol:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:audio1.aac|audio2.aac" -c copy result.aac
```